# How to select with jquery, similar elements from different DOM levels?

Tags: jquery

I would like to select only the "mixitup" elements from the same level clicking on one of this elements.

```
<div data-id="0">
    <div class="mixitup">1</div>
    <div class="mixitup">2</div>
    <div class="mixitup">3</div>
</div>
<div data-id="1">
    <div class="mixitup">4</div>
    <div class="mixitup">5</div>
    <div class="mixitup">6</div>
</div>
```

I mean. If I click in the DIV with contents = 4, I would like to select the DIVs 4,5 and 6.

Someone know a way to do it?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to select all of them including the one you picked. http://jsfiddle.net/kwnDS/1/

```
$('.mixitup').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings().andSelf();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to deselect any previous matches.

Answer (score 1):

Siblings, including the self element, would be accomplished by finding the parent and select all of its children (not descendants):

```
$(".mixitup").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children().doSomething();
});
```

Comment: it should be `$(this).parent().children("div.mixitup").doSomething();`

Comment: I agree, but I feel like it's unnecessary if you know you want to select all of the siblings. If there were other children in the parent div, I would definitely add the selector for the children(). Ignoring it in this case (if applicable) reduces that extra processing.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to select the clicked element's parent, you should simply select it's siblings and itself:

```
$(".mixitup").on("click", function(e) {
  $('.mixitup').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).siblings().andSelf().addClass("clicked");
}​);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/G4Bny/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the siblings selector:

```
$('.mixitup').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings('.mixitup'); //this selects siblings of an element;
})
```